# Citable source for "Standard deviation of sample standard deviation"?

Tags: estimation, standard-deviation

I wanted to ask if anyone knows a good book for citing, which handles the topic of "calculating / approximating the standard deviation for an estimated standard deviation from a finite sample". It is explained wonderfully in this PDF (https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/papers/files/tr/stderr.pdf), but I'm not sure if this article is eligible for citation.

Comment: it has 31 citations on scholar so it seems that it is ok to cite it: https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=en&q=Standard+errors+of+mean%2C+variance%2C+and+standard+deviation+estimators&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=